# Populating a textbox in ASP.NET without reloading the page?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, textbox

I have a listbox, a textbox, and a button. The button populates the textbox with the selected item & value of the listbox. As below:

```
Protected Sub GetVariables_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles GetVariables.Click
    Me.txtLetter.Text = lstNames.SelectedItem.ToString & lstNames.SelectedValue.ToString
End Sub
```

The problem I have, is that when doing this it reloads the page each time. Any way around this?

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options.

1. Set the value in the textbox using javascript on the client.
2. Use ajax.

For this type of extremely simple thing, use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript to do this. Textboxes are given a Client ID by ASP.NET when they are outputted to the web browser. You'll need that ID to be able to make changes to the textbox - the Client ID translates to the id property of the HTML element.

There's a number of ways of doing it, one of which is to create a hidden HTML field containing the [yourtextboxname].ClientID property. You can then use Javascript to read in the value of the hidden field, and select the element and do stuff with it.